# horizontally scrollable html box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display a log on a page , but the log has very long lines (it is an apache access_log) an it gets both ugly and unreadable.

how can i display the content with a horizontal scrollbar ?

i am using bootstrap and tried using `overflow : auto/scroll` and fixing height/width without success.

edit:
here is my code

```
<div class="well" style="overflow-x: scroll;width:200px;" >
<?php
    echo $log;
?>
</div>
```

$log contains `<br/>` for new lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll;white-space:nowrap;width:200px;
height:200px;border:1px solid red" >
    A Very long line gjkdddddssssss sssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssss
ssssssssssss ssss
ssssssss
ssssssssssssss sssssssssssssssssssssssss ss
sssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssss
    </div>​
```

White-Space is property you need to set.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/amandeepj/ZQuKG/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `overflow-x` for your output

http://www.css3.info/overflow-xoverflow-y/

you can get better info from this link so that you can udsntand this thing

Comment: i tried overflow-x but did'nt work
and the site you provided has errors (at least in firefox)

Comment: @maazza give me link of your site

Comment: cant , it is for an internal admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to this

**HTML**

```
<div class="ok">heli msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample helo i msample </div>
```

**Css**

```
    .ok{
    background:red;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      overflow:scroll;
word-break: break-all;
    }
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/c1bl0Njr)***

Comment: does not work , scollbar appears but does nothing
EDIT: vertical scroll works not horizonal

Answer (score 0):

To prevent line wraps use:
CSS

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Then you can control scroll with `overflow` property.